# Utf-8 SQL Searching

Tags: node.js, db2, ibm-cloud

I am using IBM Cloud Function binding with Db2 in cloud.
`querySync` can't search any result when my `eventname` is Chinese,
but it work when `eventname` is English.
My database is based on utf-8.

```js
    function fetchEventByclassname(dsn, eventname) {
    try {
       var conn=ibmdb.openSync(dsn);
       var data=conn.querySync("SELECT time FROM courses WHERE classname=?",[eventname]);
       conn.closeSync();
       var resString="Data:";
       return {result : resString, data : data, input: eventname};
    } catch (e) {
        return { dberror : e }
    }
   }
```

Comment: How is the eventname encoded? There are rules for string comparison https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0008479.html and it could be an issue of how the data is passed in.

Comment: Thanks for you response,
the eventname is the input from Watson Assistant,
we are using the method from https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-slack-chatbot-database-watson&locale=en

Comment: the response we got is "\u001a\u001a\u001a\u001a\u001a\u001a\u001a"

Comment: Are you using the recent code version of the tutorial with webhooks or the older with direct calls to functions?